# not able to set visibilty of a button using shared preferences

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I created an image gallery app.

My requirment:When I click on buttoncut in a activity(PhotosActivity.java), buttonpaste should become visible and it should remain visible when I go back to another activity(ImageGallery.java) so that I can use it for moving pictures to another folder.Also *buttonpaste* should become visible only when I click on *buttoncut* and it should be invisible when I open first activity (Imagegallery.java) for the first time.

What is happening: *buttonpaste* is already visible when I open first activity (Imagegallery.java) for the first time.Everything else is working fine.

I tried some code but its not working. How can I fix it ?

**PhotosActivity.java**:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("Name",true);
    editor.apply();
    Intent intent = new Intent(PhotosActivity.this,ImageGallery.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**ImageGallery.java**

```
 final ImageButton buttonpaste = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonpaste);
        buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean Namestr=(preferences.getBoolean("Name",true));
        if(Namestr){
            buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Use [StartActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) . And do some research before directly posting question here . Thx .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a button visible from another activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951270/how-to-set-a-button-visible-from-another-activity-in-android)

Comment: try editor.commit?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
boolean Namestr=(preferences.getBoolean("Name",true));
```

So if you did not write anything with key "Name" to `SharedPreferences`, the default value is `true`. This means that `buttonPaste` is visible by default. To change this, you have to set `false`as default value:

```
boolean Namestr=(preferences.getBoolean("Name",false));
```