# how to set visiblity of view based on activity intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-view

I am going on same activity from two different activities but when i come from `Activity_A` to `Activity_B`, i want view visible but when i came `Activity_C` to `Activity_B` i want that view visibility `gone` so how can i achieve this

I tried `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` like given in below solution

[How to set a button visible from another activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951270/how-to-set-a-button-visible-from-another-activity-in-android)

But using `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`, I am not getting `visibility` visible of view so is there any way to set visibility based on activity from which we are coming.

Comment: add a bundle to your intent

Comment: how using bundle can u please show it some code?

Comment: no, you didn't understand my question ii want to set visibility based on from which activity we are going in another activity please see the question again.

Comment: don't want to pass data between activity only want to hide view if i came from activity a and Visible view if i came from activity B.

Comment: passing data is HOW you will achieve that

Comment: @a_local_nobody i want exactly as the below accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass some meta-data to recognize from which activity you are coming.

While going to activity B from activity A

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("some_key","A");
startActivity(i);
```

While going to activity B from activity C

```
Intent i = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("some_key","C");
startActivity(i);
```

In activity B you can test from which activity you are coming.

```
String activity = getIntent().getExtra("some_key");

if(activity.equals("C")){
    // hide your view
}
else{
    // show your view
}
```