# How to update Button visibility from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to call this function from another class.

How do I call it from another classs?.

It¡ss not possible to achieve using normal function call, as I am not getting access to the view of the main function.

```
 public class Blank  extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call);
        Button buttonHangup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHangup);
        Button buttonHanup2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHangup2);
        }
 
    public void bringBack(){

        Button buttonHangup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHangup);
        Button buttonHanup2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHangup2);
        buttonHangup.setText("Hangup no ok ");
        buttonHanup2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


}
```

how can i call this bringback function from another class as its not allowed to call using normal method call ...as i dont get access to button view from another class
eg

```
 Blank bl =new Blank();
     bl.bringback()
```

it wont work as i dont get access to button view ..

Comment: Hi @James, please, add more details from which classes do you want to call this method,where is this method, etc..

Paste the need of the other files, so we can help you

Comment: hi @Shudy   i have updated question with code. my main issue is i dont get access to view from method called outside from its class

Comment: Follow this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34951687/11138845

Answer (score 0):

you can't call a graphical interface that way because blank extends from activity so you need to have the interaction with the layout.

What you could do is create a fragment with your own layout and embed it in different activities.

You could use a fragment that contains a button and this load it in your activities, for this you must create a framelayout within the layout of your activity where your fragment will be visible.

**activity layout**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZt3j.jpg)

**Now you must create a fragment that contains a button**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZF4J.jpg)

**Now you must load this fragment in your activity** (if at some point you don't need it anymore you can empty the framelayout or make it invisible)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auP85.jpg)

In this way you can use the same button in different activities